# Is it possible to show the console when executing a jar file?

Tags: java, console-application

I've looked into other questions and researched but nothing seems to work. I just want my program to show the console when executing the jar file. Instead of having to open a editor and execute it from there.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Isn't it what the classic `HelloWorld` application does?

Comment: By "*editor*" you mean `IDE` (like `Eclipse`, etc) right?

Answer (score 1):

> If you want console in window.Means you execute jar.Console opens up
>   for you.

You can make a JFrame and  add textArea there.Forward all the output from console there and you got yourself console.

> If you want to see console bud dont want to make any UI.

Open jar thru  **cmd**: with command **java -jar MyJar.jar**  .. then you will be able to see console.

Comment: Does not matter if you have a UI.. executing with `java.exe` will always show the console whereas `javaw.exe` won't.